# RGB-D SLAM (Non-ROS) Error: octomap_server/OctomapServerConfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System description: Ubuntu 11.10, 64-bit, with ROS Fuerte installed

I followed the directions for the "non-ROS" installation of RGBDSLAM, as indicated here:

> ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_Non-ROS_Users

The process is smooth until the very end, where I attempt to *make* the package, using:

> rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg

The error occurs during compilation; the terminal output is as follows:

> [ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o
> In file included from /home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/ColorOctomapServer.h:4:0,
> from /home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_manager.h:31,
> from /home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/openni_listener.h:30,
> from /home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/main.cpp:17:
> /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/include/octomap_server/OctomapServer.h:50:48: fatal error: octomap_server/OctomapServerConfig.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.o] Error 1
> make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
> make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/magnate/ros/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
> [ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
> [ rosmake ]    /home/magnate/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130211-032124/rgbdslam/build_output.log
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 13.96 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam.
> [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 47 packages with 1 failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory

If anyone has insight about what the issue might be, and how it could be resolved, it would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54890/rgb-d-slam-(non-ros)-error:-octomap_server/octomapserverconfig.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [magnate](https://answers.ros.org/users/4177/magnate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [magnate](https://answers.ros.org/users/4177/magnate/) on 2013-02-11**:
@Felix-Endres (below): Thanks mate, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to apply the patch in the rgbdslam folder:

```
roscd rgbdslam
sudo patch /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/manifest.xml <octomap_server_manifest.patch
```

Not your fault, the fact is missing from the walkthrough you followed, I'll add it.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maheshwar Venkat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4623/maheshwar-venkat/) on 2013-05-08**:
is there any such patch available for groovy? i'm facing the same problem with groovy

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-13**:
If I remember correctly, the patch is actually not required anymore because the octomap_server has been updated. Otherwise, just look into the patch file, it's only one line that adds some definitions. Should work for the respective file in groovy too.